# Communication between widgets

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, widget, arcgis

i'm new in flex, and im working on Webmapping application using flex 4.6, java, and sql server as database, i'm just trying to make a communication between wigdets, i would like to copy each selected item of my combobox in widget1, and show it in the textinput in widget2, i just followed this steps explaind by Robert here http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/138...+communication but no luck, the problem that i'm facing is that i can't call components of the first widget (textinput, button....) from the second widget, they are often underlined !!

at jump you found the change i made,

Widget 1

```
var layoutArr:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
            private function widgetCommunication1():void
            {
                addSharedData("Liste des chapitres", layoutArr); 
            }
```

Widget 2

```
<viewer:BaseWidget xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                   xmlns:viewer="com.esri.viewer.*"
                   width="638" height="552" creationComplete="application1_applicationCompleteHandler(event)" 
                   initialize="basewidget1_initializeHandler(event)">

<fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

                        import com.esri.viewer.AppEvent;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
    protected function basewidget1_initializeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                ViewerContainer.addEventListener(AppEvent.DATA_PUBLISH, sharedDataUpdated);
            }

 private function sharedDataUpdated(event:AppEvent):void
            {
                var data:Object = event.data;               
                if (data.key == "Liste des chapitres")

                {
                    dplist.selectedIndex = ***IntChap***.text;
                } 
            }   

]]>
    </fx:Script>

<s:DropDownList id="dplist" x="10" y="10" width="282" height="26" labelField="IntituleChap" dataProvider="{RemoteRapportDao.Selection.lastResult}" change="dplist_changeHandler(event)" ></s:DropDownList>
```

IntChap which is bold & italic is the textinput in widget1 , i got it underlined in widget 2, even if i made this communication
any one can tell me what i'm messing ??
any help or code will be appreciated !

Comment: Could you show the class containing Widget 1 and Widget 2?  This should be a simple fix, but it involves changes to that container class.

Comment: Thank you a lot Brian for replying, but it works now very well, i found an other way to do it ;)

Comment: In that case, I'd recommend posting an answer to your question -- that way it will help the next person struggling with a similar problem.

Comment: Hi Saadia, you got the problem resolved? Is it possible to share your experience, I still cannot make it work. You use the sample code in the below answer? it uses flex viewer 2.5, but I am using 3.6, so it also not work. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://web.zone.ee/bespiva/
there is an example on the link above, just follow all the steps, it works very well ;)

Comment: this is the answer user30643

Comment: Hi Saadia, so lucky you can see my comment. I have already tried the code in the above-mentioned link. But I am using flex api 3.6(the sample use 2.5). In 3.6 it will cause eror when I use : this.widgetAttributes. Which version of arcgis flex api version you use? Thank you!

Comment: Hi Saadia, I have updated my code according to sample code, but still not work. May I check with you the type of parameter you pass to the other widget? I just want to pass a string to another widget, but no luck. Is it possible to share your code of sharing data? thank you very much!